# ImportError: No module named even after I appended to system path

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following files:

```
./ElementExtractor.py
./test/ElementExtractorTest.py
```

In `ElementExtractorTest.py`, I am trying to import `ElementExtractor.py` like this:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../')
import ElementExtractor
```

However, I am getting:

```
ImportError: No module named 'ElementExtractor'
```

How come it's not seen?

Is there a simple way to import another class with a relative reference?

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? How are you calling the `ElementExtractorTest.py` script exactly? Is it `python3 ./ElementExtractorTest.py` or is it `python3 ./test/ElementExtractorTest.py`?

Comment: I ssuggest that you read [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time).

Comment: version is `3.5.1`. I'm just calling `python ./test/ElementExtractorTest.py`

Answer (score 3):

The general answer to this question should be *don't*, I guess. Messing with **relative** paths means that the path is relative to the place **from where you're calling it**. That's why `PYTHONPATH` is worth embracing instead.

Let's assume, your directory structure looks like this:

```
./projects/myproject/ElementExtractor.py
./projects/myproject/test/ElementExtractorTest.py
```

Now, you're calling your script like this:

```
[./projects/myproject]$ python3.5 ./test/ElementExtractorTest.py
```

Your current directory is `myproject` and in `ElementExtractorTest.py` you're adding `../` directory to `sys.path`. This means, that `./projects/myproject/../` (i.e.: `./projects`) is effectively added to your PYTHONPATH. That' why Python is unable to locate your module.

Your code would work from `test` directory though:

```
[./projects/myproject/test]$ python3.5 ./ElementExtractorTest.py
```

Now, by adding `..` to `sys.path` you are effectively adding `./projects/myproject/test/../` (i.e. `./projects/myproject`) to `sys.path`, so the module can be found and imported.

Answer (score -2):

my folder structure

```
 ./test.py
 ./Data.py
```

from test.py

```
import Data
obj = Data.Myclass()
```

### update

in your case

```
from ..ElementExtractor import MyClass
```

Hope this helps :)